# JdbcTemplate calling stored procedure call

Tags: stored-procedures, java-8, jdbctemplate

I know this its easy to call stored procedure call using `JdbcTemplate`, but here the situation what I am having is different. I want to call a stored procedure function which does not returns anything. I tried the below code and it works fine but we are not using `RowCountCallbackHandler` by any means and its a waste

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from status_update(?) ",
                new Object[]{statusId},
                new int[]{Types.INTEGER}, new RowCountCallbackHandler());
```

What I am looking is something like the below which apparently is not available

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from status_update(?) ",
                new Object[]{statusId},
                new int[]{Types.INTEGER});
```

I would like to know if I am missing any other way to execute a void stored procedure using JdbcTemplate

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SimpleJdbcCall` class. This has overloaded `execute()` methods out of which one can satisfy your need.

```java
SimpleJdbcCall spCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(yourJdbcTemplate);
spCall.withProcedureName(SP_NAME);
spcall.execute(inParamsAsMap);
```

This will do the execution. If your SP has output params, you can do like below.

```java
Map<String, Object> output = spCall.execute(inParamsAsMap);
```

[Doc link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html)